# Failed to find affinity server node with data storage configuration for starting cache

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

I'm trying to store Spark in-memory table into Ignite. When I try to do that I gets an error message as

> Failed to find affinity server node with data storage configuration for starting cache  [cacheName=SQL_PUBLIC_JSON_TBL, aliveSrvNodes=[]].

I'm running it in a HDP cluster setup in a Ec2 machine but when I do the same in the cluster machine here it works perfectly but not in the EC2 machine.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I'm using Spark shell. Here's the code.

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("~/responses")
val s = df.select("response.id","response.name")
s.write.format(IgniteDataFrameSettings.FORMAT_IGNITE).option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CONFIG_FILE, "~/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/examples/config/spark/example-shared-rdd.xml").option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_FIELDS,"id").option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_TABLE, "json_table").save()
```

Here is the xml config file that I use for my single Ignite server:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
        <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
            <property name="cacheConfiguration">
                <!-- SharedRDD cache example configuration (Atomic mode). -->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <!-- Set a cache name. -->
                    <property name="name" value="sharedRDD"/>
                    <!-- Set a cache mode. -->
                    <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                    <!-- Index Integer pairs used in the example. -->
                    <property name="indexedTypes">
                        <list>
                            <value>java.lang.Integer</value>
                            <value>java.lang.Integer</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                    <!-- Set atomicity mode. -->
                    <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                    <!-- Configure a number of backups. -->
                    <property name="backups" value="1"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="discoverySpi">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                    <property name="ipFinder">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                            <property name="addresses">
                                <list>
                                    <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                    <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

Here's the full log.

> 18/10/30 12:32:54 WARN GridDiagnostic: Initial heap size is 252MB (should be no less than 512MB, use -Xms512m -Xmx512m).
>   18/10/30 12:32:54 WARN TcpCommunicationSpi: Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
>   18/10/30 12:32:55 WARN NoopCheckpointSpi: Checkpoints are disabled (to enable configure any GridCheckpointSpi implementation)
>   18/10/30 12:32:55 WARN GridCollisionManager: Collision resolution is disabled (all jobs will be activated upon arrival).
>   18/10/30 12:32:57 WARN TcpDiscoverySpi: Failed to read message due to ClassNotFoundException (make sure same versions of all classes are available on all nodes) [rmtNodeId=3085dfa9-58ba-4ac0-a7f8-f78e2901a699, err=o.a.i.i.processors.hadoop.HadoopAttributes]
>   18/10/30 12:32:57 WARN IgniteAuthenticationProcessor: Cannot find the server coordinator node. Possible a client is started with forceServerMode=true. Security warning: user authentication will be disabled on the client.
>   18/10/30 12:32:58 ERROR ClusterCachesInfo: Failed to find affinity server node with data storage configuration for starting cache [cacheName=SQL_PUBLIC_JSON_TBL6, aliveSrvNodes=[]]
>   18/10/30 12:32:58 WARN CacheAffinitySharedManager: No server nodes found for cache client: SQL_PUBLIC_JSON_TBL

Comment: Please provide used Ignite configuration and DDL statement. Also it would be nice if you provided log, preceding this error message.

Answer (score 0):

The log contains the following record:

```
12:32:57 WARN TcpDiscoverySpi: Failed to read message due to ClassNotFoundException (make sure same versions of all classes are available on all nodes) [rmtNodeId=3085dfa9-58ba-4ac0-a7f8-f78e2901a699, err=o.a.i.i.processors.hadoop.HadoopAttributes]
```

It says, that a discovery message cannot be deserialized because `HadoopAttributes` class is not on the classpath. It may lead to connectivity problems and affect ability of nodes to see each other.

Make sure, that all nodes have `ignite-hadoop` module on their classpath, or get rid of this dependency.

Comment: I've added ignite-hadoop in the classpath but still the same error.                        
 18/10/31 06:39:27 ERROR ClusterCachesInfo: Failed to find affinity server node with data storage configuration for starting cache [cacheName=SQL_PUBLIC_JSON_TBL, aliveSrvNodes=[]]
18/10/31 06:39:27 WARN CacheAffinitySharedManager: No server nodes found for cache client: SQL_PUBLIC_JSON_TBL

Comment: @user77 could you update the question to the actual state? What do you see in the log now?